# предикат типа C++

Tags: c++

Как работает предикат типа C++?

```
template<typename T>
    requires Element<T>()
class Vector {};
```

интересует реализация `Element<T>()`

Comment: Это в C++20 такое появилось, в концептах? А какой-нибудь компилятор уже это поддерживает, чтобы проверить?

Comment: Ага, из книги Страуструпа, 19.3.3.

Comment: я у Страуструпа прочел. мой vs17 не поддерживает.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Element<T>() - это просто некая шаблонная (с одним шаблонным параметром T) constexpr (вычислимая на этапе компиляции) функция которая должна вернуть true если T обладает нужными свойствами и false если нет. Т.е. если проще requires указывает на bool выражение этапа компиляции которое проверяет что шаблонные типы подходящии для данной специализации, т.е. requires просто условия в удобном виде накладывает на типы шаблонные.